# Java array assignment in functions

Tags: java, arrays, variable-assignment

```
public static void mystery(int[] arr) {
    int[] tmp = new int[arr.length];
    tmp[0] = arr[arr.length-1];
    tmp[arr.length-1] = arr[0];
    arr = tmp;
}

int[] a = {2,3,4};
mystery(a);
```

When I run this, I get that even after calling mystery(a), the value of a is still

```
a = {2,3,4};
```

Java arrays are mutable, and all arguments are pass by reference. Since in the method arr points to the memory stored in tmp after the method, why is a unchanged?

Comment: You can alter one or all of the indexes in the array inside your function, but that form of assignment does not work.

Comment: If we consider StackOverflow as a guide for programming in <any> language, I think this question/answer is beneficial apart from the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [java](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) changing the argument of a method to refer to some other object does not have any effect on the original argument. 
Therefor a does not point to tmp after the execution of `mystery`.

To accomplish the swapping your `mystery` method needs to work on `arr` directly

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that it made a copy of the reference variable. I thought the reference variable was reference as well. Perfect.